# Why does Github reccomend using git merge --ff-only @{upstream} when checking out a branch locally?

Tags: git, github

**Question background**: I need to test somebody else's code locally which is located on a remote branch. I have noticed that Git Hub has a button that shows the user which commands to use to check out a branch locally. Here is an screenshot of those commands below:

[image]

Why do they recommend to do it this way? What are the advantages? For example, why not use git pull? And why use the --ff-only @{upstream}?

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

They probably *could* suggest using `git pull` but it might produce the wrong results more often.

#### Long

> For example, why not use git pull?

`git pull`:

1. runs `git fetch`, then
2. runs a command of the user's choice.  The standard default here is `git merge`, but you can explicitly ask for rebase with `git rebase`.  But you can also pre-configure Git so that you don't have to explicitly ask for it with `git pull --rebase`, and get `git rebase` anyway.

If that second command is `git rebase`, that's the wrong command.  So if the user has already chosen `git rebase` over `git merge`, that doesn't necessarily do what we'd like to have happen.

Even if the user's setup has Git run `git merge`, this is a `git merge` with no `--ff-only` option.

> And why use the --ff-only @{upstream}?

The `@{upstream}` part is not actually required as it is the default if you omit it, so `git merge --ff-only` suffices.

The `--ff-only` option tells Git that if a fast-forward *isn't* possible, it should fail the merge entirely, rather than performing a real merge.

So the goal here is to make sure that:

1. a fast-forward is possible, and
2. a fast-forward is used.

Given the sequence of commands shown here, fast-forward is likely to be possible and the default, which makes the `--ff-only` *probably* redundant.  But it's not *provably* redundant and it will fail if:

- the user already has the branch name in question, and
- the user has made some commits of their own on their branch.

This particular invocation will catch that particular error: the merge attempt will fail and the user will probably post a question on StackOverflow. :-)

It *will not* catch one other possible user error.  If the user has (a) created the local branch but then (b) set its upstream to something other than `origin/202005_rediscover_inges...` (some text seems to be cut off here), the `git merge --ff-only`, with or without an explicit `@{upstream}`, may fast-forward to the wrong commit.

Presumably the GitHub folks are not worried about this particular possible user error.  It's not clear to me why they worry more about the "user has branch and has made commits of their own" error case, but that does seem to be more likely than "user has branch and has set an inappropriate upstream".

> Why do they recommend to do it this way?

Presumably, because it works well in practice.

The goal in all of these cases is to make the (local) branch name `202005_rediscover_inges...` (again, some seems cut off here) point to the same commit as the updated `origin/202005_rediscover_inges...` that is the result of the initial `git fetch`.  These commands will do the trick in all but the cases I noted.  Other commands might succeed as well, but in somewhat fewer cases.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. There is a lot here for a git beginner-intermediate user to understand the *why*, but I'm definitely going to review the answer more thoroughly. I thought this would be a useful post for others who may stumble upon this question.